# Form recognizer(custom model with labels) is not fetching proper data

Tags: ocr, azure-cognitive-services, azure-form-recognizer

Currently, I am using **Form Recognizer version 2.1 preview** to extract data from PDF file which contains scanned images. The text is fetched properly but mapping of values with labels is not as expected. I am using custom model [Train with labels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/) to extract data from the file and using [FOTT website](https://fott-preview.azurewebsites.net/) to label data which is giving the functionality to label data manually. I have trained model with manually labeled data for 5 pages which is not giving proper response. And also tried [Train without labels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/) is not giving proper result. However, the model is not giving exact result. Some labels are not fetched and some labels are having incomplete values in the result. I have read documentation from [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/) for learning about this cognitive service. It is not giving proper result as expected and I am not getting what is the issue with this. So, I want to know that what can be possible reason for not getting proper result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When training a model are you using 5 documents from the same structure ? To improve the model you can also add a few additional documents so that your training data represents the documents you are trying to extract data from. When analyzing a document if a key value pair is missed you can add that document to the training data and train the model so that it can improve for that document also.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Neta Yes, I am using 5 documents from the same structure. But it is not giving values of some fields which I have labeled manually while training and also done training by the document which is not analyzed properly.

Comment: If you add the documents with a miss to the training and train the model does the model improve and extract the data ? 
Feel free to also reach out to Form Recognizer Contact Us <formrecog_contact@microsoft.com> or support